# Роль Entity в приложении с Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, coredata

Делаю приложение в котором есть несколько ViewController'ов с таблицами, каждая из которых будет содержать свой fetchedResultsController. Типы данных (attributes в Entity):

FirstTableViewController: string

SecondTableViewController: string, date, BOOL

данные для каждого контроллера выводятся свои, никак между собой не связаны и никак друг на друга не влияют. Можно ли в таком случае использовать одну Entity c несколькими атрибутами вместо двух Entity с одним атрибутом в одной и с тремя во второй. Если ли недостатки у метода при котором я все атрибуты для всех контроллеров положу в одну сущность?

Comment: Можете привести пример кода, который вы используете для создания одного типа? И можете ли вы описать типы хотя бы двух данных и структуры этих типов данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте просто различные контексты. И это будет правильный выход из ситуации во многопоточном приложении. Так же конетксы имеют события на изменения. Таким образом их можно мерджить для поддержки всегда свежих данных. Почитайте официальную документацию по работе с [CoreData Concurent](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) очень полезная штука.